# Moving dev site to production on new account AWS

Tags: magento, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting

I am in the process of moving and testing a development site on the actual domain name now and I just wanted to check if I was missing anything and also get some advice.

It is a Magento 1.8.1 install from Turnkey Linux running on an m1.medium instance.

What I have done (so far) is, create an image of the development instance, made a new account and copied it over to there. I then made an elastic IP and associated it with the new instance. Next I pointed the A name record of the production domain to the elastic IP.

Now, if I go to the production domain I get redirected to the development domain. Is there a reason for this?

Ideally I would like to have two instances, one dev one that is off unless needed and of course the production on which is going to be live 24/7. However if I turn the development domain off it stops the other too.

I have a feeling it's just because I need to change instances of the dev domain in the Magento database / back-end however I wanted to get a more knowledgable answer as I don't want to break either of the instance.

Also, I should probably mention that the development domain is a subdomain i.e. shop.mysite.com and the live one is just normal i.e. mysite.com. Not entirely sure this is relevant but thought it worth a mention.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your URL on your new instance is getting redirected to the old URL is because in the `core_config_data` table of your `magento` database the `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` paths point to your old URL.

So if you are using mysql you can query your database as follows:

```
mysql> use magento;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> select * from core_config_data;
+-----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                          | value                               |
+-----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|         1 | default |        0 | web/seo/use_rewrites          | 1                                    |
|         2 | default |        0 | admin/dashboard/enable_charts | 0                                   |
|         3 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_url         | http://magento.myolddomain.com/         |
|         4 | default |        0 | web/secure/use_in_frontend    | 1                                   |
|         5 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_url           | https://magento.myolddomain.com/        |
|         6 | default |        0 | web/secure/use_in_adminhtml   | 1                                   |
|         7 | default |        0 | general/locale/code           | en_US                               |
|         8 | default |        0 | general/locale/timezone       | Europe/London                       |
|         9 | default |        0 | currency/options/base         | USD                                 |
|        10 | default |        0 | currency/options/default      | USD                                 |
|        11 | default |        0 | currency/options/allow        | USD                                 |
|        12 | default |        0 | general/region/display_all    | 1                                   |
|        13 | default |        0 | general/region/state_required | AT,CA,CH,DE,EE,ES,FI,FR,LT,LV,RO,US |
|        14 | default |        0 | catalog/category/root_id      | 2                                   |
+-----------+---------+----------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and you can change it as follows:

```
mysql> update core_config_data set value='http://magento.mynewdomain.com' where path='web/unsecure/base_url';
mysql> update core_config_data set value='https://magento.mynewdomain.com' where path='web/secure/base_url';
```

Comment: Hey this all sounds perfect but the worry I have is that I want both sites to work. If I change the URLs in core_config_data wouldn't this allow the development site move over to production but in turn kill the dev site? The reason I ask is because I want to be able to test updates change etc on the dev site in the future. Any thoughts on this? EDIT: Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: My mistake, for some reason I was thinking of the databases/servers as one rather than two identical copies. This worked perfectly! Thanks for all the help :)